# Plotting multiple fitobjects in the same figure in MATLAB 2016b

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting

I have multiple fitobjects that I want to plot in the same figure. All curves are fitted from the same five points on the x-axes (ranging from 0.25 to 2.25). If I plot them individually the curve correctly spans only between does values, however, as soon as I add hold on to plot them in the same figure the first fitobject is plotted correctly, while the second spans from -Inf to +Inf, if I change the order of fitobjects the problem remains. So the first curve is always shown correctly the following ones are not. I am not even setting any axes properties yet. Also the two fitobjects have the same Boundaries for the fit.

Example code:

```
plot(fitobj{1}, 'r'); hold on %curve from 0.25 to 2.25
plot(fitobj{2}, 'b'); %curve is shown from -Inf to +Inf
```

Do you know why this is happening? Thank you

Comment: you can set how much of the axis is show with `axis()`, or just `xlim()` in your case.  is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Even if I set xlim the problem remains. The strange thing is that if I try to plot each curve individually they correctly span from the first to the last data point, the problem presents when I try to show more than one at the same time, I am not sure if I am using hold on incorrectly then..

Comment: no you are not. But what you say its not how MATLAB behaves, so unless you show us code that we can reproduce, including your example with `xlim()`, we can't really help. Are you using `xlim()` at the end? othewise it gets overwritten by the next call to `plot()`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]